# Jsf with ajax call to get dynamic values with polling

Tags: jquery, ajax, multithreading, jsf, polling

Onclick of button my ajax is calling managed bean yourFileData method. In yourFileData() i have created a new thread from main thread. So I want to execute the main thread on first attempt and new thread will be running and will refresh my row count so i can dynamically update that count on my modal.

I have also created a dummy button to refresh my hiddenCurrentRowCount but that didn't help me and I'm also refreshing for every 5 seconds.

Code in snippet is just for your view purpose nothing works there.

```js
function ajaxValidateFile(data) {
                 var status = data.status;
                        
                 switch (status) {
                     case "begin":
                      refreshRowCount();
                         break;
 
                     case "complete":
                         break;
 
                     case "success":
                         openModalWindow();
                         break;
                 }
            }


  var refreshRowTimer;
    function refreshRowCount(){
      refreshRowTimer = setInterval(refreshRowCount, 5000);
      $("#dummyHiddenBtn").click();
        currentCount = $("#hiddenCurrentRowCount").val();
         $("#validateMsg").html('<p>Validating ' + currentCount + ' of '+ totalCount + ' records </p>');
              
    if($("#hiddenTotalRowCount").val() === $("#hiddenCurrentRowCount").val()){
               clearInterval(refreshRowTimer);
               $( '#dialog' ).modal( 'close' );
               console.log('Here you go');
              }
            }



openModalWindow = function() {
     totalCount = $("#hiddenTotalRowCount").val();
      currentCount = $("#hiddenCurrentRowCount").val();
      $("#validateMsg").html('<p> Validating ' + currentCount + ' of '+ totalCount + ' records </p>');
     $( '#dialog' ).modal( 'open' );
   
    };
```

```html
I have jsf code below :

<div>
<h:commandButton id="validateFileBtn" value="Validate File" >
<f:ajax execute="uploadCsvFile" event="click" listener="#{formManagedBean.yourFileData}" render="validateFileBtn hiddenTotalRowCount dummyHiddenBtn hiddenCurrentRowCount messagesDiv :csvFilesForm" onevent="ajaxValidateFile" onerror="ajaxOnError"/>
</h:commandButton>
</div>
                                 
<h:commandButton id="formManagedBean" styleClass="dol-hide" >
<f:ajax listener="#{formManagedBean.dummyCallRefreshData}" render="hiddenCurrentRowCount"/>
</h:commandButton>

<h:inputHidden id="hiddenTotalRowCount" value="#{formManagedBean.lineCount}" rendered="#{not empty formManagedBean.lineCount}"></h:inputHidden>

<h:inputHidden id="hiddenCurrentRowCount" value="#{formManagedBean.rowNum}" rendered="#{not empty formManagedBean.rowNum}"></h:inputHidden>


public List<String> yourFileData(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
         try {

             // code running for LineCount before new thread and it works fine

              Thread one = new Thread(){

                       public void run() {
                   try{
                           String input;

               while((input = bfReaderCount.readLine()) != null){
                  rowNum++;
               }                   

                    }catch(Exception e){

                           e.printStackTrace();

                   }

                  }

                };

                one.start();

                System.out.println("Does it work NOOOOOOO?");

         } catch (Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return someList;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a ScheduledExecutorService to refresh model value periodically in server side by passing model object reference to the executor.
2. Use primefaces poll component to refresh data periodically at client side.
   https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml

You can also use websocket.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we don't use any primefaces.

Comment: @Nain: Then use OmniFaces or JSF2.3... Creating your own 'polling' is a bad choice

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanku but can you tell me why is my code not working and where am I going wrong.

Comment: I know what's the problem : my private variable rowNum is updated in new thread but it's not updated out of that thread. I'm not sure how to solve it.